# Body format for Stripe POST operations

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm accessing the stripe API directly with the REST API (not using a library) but, surprisingly, I can't find documentation on the appropriate body format post data.

Does Stripe expect JSON or form-encoded pairs?

Comment: Yes. You basically have to look at the curl examples and deduce that the body format is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to post raw data like key-value pair. (No Json)

e.g.
key1=value1&key2=value2

Make sure you include following in header
Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 5):

Here is the sample of the curl code to Nodejs
I am working on a similar problem

as you know we can't send JSON for the "post" method 
it must be URL encoded

here is the sample provided by stripe
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions \
>   -u stripe_key_here: \
>   -d success_url="https://example.com/success" \
>   -d cancel_url="https://example.com/cancel" \
>   -d "payment_method_types[]=card" \
>   -d "line_items[][name]=T-shirt" \
>   -d "line_items[][description]=Comfortable cotton t-shirt" \
>   -d "line_items[][amount]=1500" \
>   -d "line_items[][currency]=usd" \
>   -d "line_items[][quantity]=2"
```

-u means authorization which we provide in the headers

-d means body of the url

sample code in node js

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const stripeKey = process.env.STRIPE_KEY;

async function getCheckoutID() {
  try {
    const endpoint = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions";

    const query = objToQuery({
      success_url: "https://example.com/success",
      cancel_url: "https://example.com/cancel",
      "payment_method_types[]": "card",
      "line_items[][name]": "T-shirt",
      "line_items[][description]": "Comfortable cotton t-shirt",
      "line_items[][amount]": 1500,
      "line_items[][quantity]": 1,
      "line_items[][currency]": "usd"
    });

    // enpoint => "https://www.domin.com/api"
    // query => "?key=value&key1=value1"
    const URL = `${endpoint}${query}`;

    const fetchOpts = {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${stripeKey}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    }
    const checkout = await getJSON(URL, fetchOpts);

    console.log("CHECKOUT OBJECT : " , checkout);

    return checkout;
  }
  catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
}


// hepler functions

// instead of using fetch
// getJSON will make it readable code
async function getJSON(url, options) {
  const http = await fetch(url, options);
  if (!http.ok) {
    console.log(http);
    throw new Error("ERROR STATUS IS NOT OK :");
  }
  return http.json();
}

// convert JS object to url query
// {key:"value" , key1: "value1"} to "key=value&key1=value1"
function objToQuery(obj) {
  const query = Object.keys(obj).map( k => `${k}=${obj[k]}`).join("&");
  return query.length > 0 ? `?${query}` : "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form encoded pairs

The [docs for cURL](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl) provide good examples. They're just feeding form encoded key/value pairs via the `-d` switch via cURL on the command line. Just make sure you use your test secret key so you don't screw up any live data. Then you can play around all you want.

The returned data is `JSON`.

Comment: Thanks but i'm not familiar with cURL so its unclear with -d means.  It sounds like you're saying the POST is always form encoded and the response is JSON.

But if that is the case... how are users to POST the metadata element which would represent a child object ALSO containing key/value pairs... i would think you'd need JSON for that nesting of a child object.

Comment: FYI, i just noticed on https://stripe.com/blog  that the form-encoded format is: metadata[key]=value

Comment: @frigon, you legend. I couldn't find this syntax anywhere... For anyone else looking for this (keywords): Stripe API convert metadata key-value pair object to x-www-form-urlencoded string for Integromat Make HTTP request

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example cURL charge using a test card:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u your_test_key: -d card[number]=4000056655665556 -d card[exp_month]=11 -d card[exp_year]=2020 -d amount=100 -d currency=eur -d description="Stripe cUrl charge test"
```

Exchange *your_test_key* with your stripe test key. 
Remember to keep the : after your key to not get asked for a password.

Answer (score 1):

Created an account just to thank frigon and mustimpress for solving an issue that kept me up all night.

For anyone else struggling with this, particularly salesforce environment non-developers attempting to use stripes "super easy" in flow apex actions to send to an endpoint:

If you want to send this body:

```
{
  "object": "quote",
  "line_items": {
    "0": {
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": "price_132456479879"
    },
    "1": {
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": "price_84384354589"
    }
  }
}
```

it needs to look like:

```
line_items[0][price]=price_132456479879&line_items[0][quantity]=1&line_items[1][price]=price_84384354589&line_items[0][quantity]=1
```